# How do I mask a loss function in Keras with the TensorFlow backend?

Tags: keras, lstm, masking, loss-function

I am trying to implement a sequence-to-sequence task using LSTM by Keras with the TensorFlow backend. The inputs are English sentences with variable lengths. To construct a dataset with 2-D shape `[batch_number, max_sentence_length]`, I add `EOF` at the end of the line and pad each sentence with enough placeholders, e.g. `#`. And then each character in the sentence is transformed into a one-hot vector, so that the dataset has 3-D shape `[batch_number, max_sentence_length, character_number]`.  After LSTM encoder and decoder layers, softmax cross-entropy between output and target is computed.

To eliminate the padding effect in model training, masking could be used on input and loss function. Mask input in Keras can be done by using `layers.core.Masking`. In TensorFlow, masking on loss function can be done as follows: [custom masked loss function in TensorFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwGRy.png).

However, I don't find a way to realize it in Keras, since a user-defined loss function in Keras only accepts parameters `y_true` and `y_pred`. So how to input true `sequence_lengths` to loss function and mask?

Besides, I find a function `_weighted_masked_objective(fn)` in `\keras\engine\training.py`. Its definition is

> Adds support for masking and sample-weighting to an objective function.

But it seems that the function can only accept `fn(y_true, y_pred)`. Is there a way to use this function to solve my problem?

To be specific, I modify the example of Yu-Yang.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Masking, LSTM, Dense, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Activation
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import seed as random_seed
random_seed(123)

max_sentence_length = 5
character_number = 3 # valid character 'a, b' and placeholder '#'

input_tensor = Input(shape=(max_sentence_length, character_number))
masked_input = Masking(mask_value=0)(input_tensor)
encoder_output = LSTM(10, return_sequences=False)(masked_input)
repeat_output = RepeatVector(max_sentence_length)(encoder_output)
decoder_output = LSTM(10, return_sequences=True)(repeat_output)
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(decoder_output)

model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

X = np.array([[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]],
          [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]])
y_true = np.array([[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]], # the batch is ['##abb','#babb'], padding '#'
          [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]])

y_pred = model.predict(X)
print('y_pred:', y_pred)
print('y_true:', y_true)
print('model.evaluate:', model.evaluate(X, y_true))
# See if the loss computed by model.evaluate() is equal to the masked loss
import tensorflow as tf
logits=tf.constant(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
target=tf.constant(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(logits),axis=2))
losses = -tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(logits),axis=2)
sequence_lengths=tf.constant([3,4])
mask = tf.reverse(tf.sequence_mask(sequence_lengths,maxlen=max_sentence_length),[0,1])
losses = tf.boolean_mask(losses, mask)
masked_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    c_e = sess.run(cross_entropy)
    m_c_e=sess.run(masked_loss)
    print("tf unmasked_loss:", c_e)
    print("tf masked_loss:", m_c_e)
```

The output in Keras and TensorFlow are compared as follows:

[image]

As shown above, masking is disabled after some kinds of layers. So how to mask the loss function in Keras when those layers are added?

Comment: Do you want a dynamic masking?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko If ''dynamic masking" means masking the loss function according to the different input data of model, yes this is what I want.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If there's a mask in your model, it'll be propagated layer-by-layer and eventually applied to the loss. So if you're padding and masking the sequences in a correct way, the loss on the padding placeholders would be ignored.

### Some Details:

It's a bit involved to explain the whole process, so I'll just break it down to several steps:

1. In `compile()`, the mask is collected by calling `compute_mask()` and applied to the loss(es) (irrelevant lines are ignored for clarity).

```py
weighted_losses = [_weighted_masked_objective(fn) for fn in loss_functions]

# Prepare output masks.
masks = self.compute_mask(self.inputs, mask=None)
if masks is None:
    masks = [None for _ in self.outputs]
if not isinstance(masks, list):
    masks = [masks]

# Compute total loss.
total_loss = None
with K.name_scope('loss'):
    for i in range(len(self.outputs)):
        y_true = self.targets[i]
        y_pred = self.outputs[i]
        weighted_loss = weighted_losses[i]
        sample_weight = sample_weights[i]
        mask = masks[i]
        with K.name_scope(self.output_names[i] + '_loss'):
            output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
                                        sample_weight, mask)
```

2. Inside `Model.compute_mask()`, `run_internal_graph()` is called.
3. Inside `run_internal_graph()`, the masks in the model is propagated layer-by-layer from the model's inputs to outputs by calling `Layer.compute_mask()` for each layer iteratively.

So if you're using a `Masking` layer in your model, you shouldn't worry about the loss on the padding placeholders. The loss on those entries will be masked out as you've probably already seen inside `_weighted_masked_objective()`.

### A Small Example:

```py
max_sentence_length = 5
character_number = 2

input_tensor = Input(shape=(max_sentence_length, character_number))
masked_input = Masking(mask_value=0)(input_tensor)
output = LSTM(3, return_sequences=True)(masked_input)
model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

X = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]],
              [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]]])
y_true = np.ones((2, max_sentence_length, 3))
y_pred = model.predict(X)
print(y_pred)
[[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [-0.11980877  0.05803877  0.07880752]
  [-0.00429189  0.13382857  0.19167568]
  [ 0.06817091  0.19093043  0.26219055]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.0651961   0.10283815  0.12413475]
  [-0.04420842  0.137494    0.13727818]
  [ 0.04479844  0.17440712  0.24715884]
  [ 0.11117355  0.21645413  0.30220413]]]

# See if the loss computed by model.evaluate() is equal to the masked loss
unmasked_loss = np.abs(1 - y_pred).mean()
masked_loss = np.abs(1 - y_pred[y_pred != 0]).mean()

print(model.evaluate(X, y_true))
0.881977558136

print(masked_loss)
0.881978

print(unmasked_loss)
0.917384
```

As can be seen from this example, the loss on the masked part (the zeroes in `y_pred`) is ignored, and the output of `model.evaluate()` is equal to `masked_loss`.

---

### EDIT:

If there's a recurrent layer with `return_sequences=False`, the mask stop propagates (i.e., the returned mask is `None`). In `RNN.compute_mask()`:

```py
def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask):
    if isinstance(mask, list):
        mask = mask[0]
    output_mask = mask if self.return_sequences else None
    if self.return_state:
        state_mask = [None for _ in self.states]
        return [output_mask] + state_mask
    else:
        return output_mask
```

In your case, if I understand correctly, you want a mask that's based on `y_true`, and whenever the value of `y_true` is `[0, 0, 1]` (the one-hot encoding of "#") you want the loss to be masked. If so, you need to mask the loss values in a somewhat similar way to Daniel's answer.

The main difference is the final average. The average should be taken over the number of unmasked values, which is just `K.sum(mask)`. And also, `y_true` can be compared to the one-hot encoded vector `[0, 0, 1]` directly.

```py
def get_loss(mask_value):
    mask_value = K.variable(mask_value)
    def masked_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
        # find out which timesteps in `y_true` are not the padding character '#'
        mask = K.all(K.equal(y_true, mask_value), axis=-1)
        mask = 1 - K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        # multiply categorical_crossentropy with the mask
        loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) * mask

        # take average w.r.t. the number of unmasked entries
        return K.sum(loss) / K.sum(mask)
    return masked_categorical_crossentropy

masked_categorical_crossentropy = get_loss(np.array([0, 0, 1]))
model = Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss=masked_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam')
```

The output of the above code then shows that the loss is computed only on the unmasked values:

```
model.evaluate: 1.08339476585
tf unmasked_loss: 1.08989
tf masked_loss: 1.08339
```

The value is different from yours because I've changed the `axis` argument in `tf.reverse` from `[0,1]` to `[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, this can be work when `return_sequences=True` in LSTM . However, in encoder-decoder model, the LSTM in encoder generally set `return_sequences=False` and use RepeatVector to repeat the output of the last unit, then the LSTM in decoder accept it. To be specific, I modify your small example to show the problem. I will show it by 'answer my question' below, since the comment can't be too long.

Comment: @Shuaaai Ah, by seq2seq, I thought you mean models like the one in this [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py). I've updated the answer. Please see if that's what you want.

Comment: Firstly, many thanks to you . Yes, I want a mask that's based on `y_true`. I run your updated code, and it raises an error "ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 3 for 'Equal' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [2,5,3], [3,1]." Is this caused by different versions or something else?

Comment: My bad. I've pasted the wrong code. It should work now.

Comment: There is still an error "ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("dense_1_target:0", shape=(?, ?, ?), dtype=float32)". Maybe I make some mistake?

Comment: Umm, what are your Keras and TF versions? I test the code on Keras 2.0.9 + TF 1.3.0 and it works fine. Can you provide more information about the error?

Comment: My Keras is 2.0.4 and TF is 1.1.0. I just pull my code and error screenshot  in "https://github.com/Shuaaai/Mask-loss-function". Could you check it? Thanks.

Comment: (1) There's a `K.variable(y_true)` in your loss function, please remove the `K.variable()`. (2) For Keras 2.0.4, it should be `K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)` instead of `K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)`. The arguments are swapped in later versions. (3) The line `mask = tf.reverse(...,[0,1])` should be `mask = tf.reverse(...,[1])`. You don't want to swap the samples (axis 0), right?

Comment: Yes, I make so many mistake...  Thank you very much! My problem is solved.

Comment: Hi  Yu-Yang, I have tried this masking method on the model "https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/addition_rnn.py". I don't find explicit difference on training loss or validation loss between the original model and modified model under the same iteration number. Do you have any experience on this aspect? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry that I don't really have experience working with this model. At a first glance, I think you probably shouldn't mask out the "padding spaces" in this question. The model should learn to predict spaces if the answer contains padding spaces. Consider the example `"12 + 34 = 46"` versus `"12 + 34 = 468"`, the latter is clearly wrong. The model should output 4, 6, and a padding space given the input "12+34".

Comment: To put it differently, if the model predicts quite well, the padding positions should not incur much loss. Then it's not so important whether you masked out the padding spaces or not.

Comment: Yes, the `"12 + 34 = 468"` will be a wrong prediction given `"12 + 34 = 46"`. So I add EOF in answers (e.g., "46#   ")  and the model will learn EOF as well. Then the characters before EOF will be outputed and the padding spaces after EOF can be ignored. I guess the padding positions might have affected the model less if the model is strong enough to deal with the task, but I don't find relevent study or theoretical explanation.

Comment: Thanks for you clear answer. I have one more question: Dense layers seem to not support masking, so what happens if TimeDistributed(Dense()) is appended after an LSTM(require_sequences=True)? Will the mask be invalid?

Comment: I believe `Dense` layers support masking. Since there's no `compute_mask` function implemented in `Dense`, by default the mask should just propagate through the layer, without modification.

Comment: @Yu-Yang what could be the equivalent of this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using masks as in Yu-Yang's answer, you can try this.

If you have your target data `Y` with length and padded with the mask value, you can:

```
import keras.backend as K
def custom_loss(yTrue,yPred):

    #find which values in yTrue (target) are the mask value
    isMask = K.equal(yTrue, maskValue) #true for all mask values

    #since y is shaped as (batch, length, features), we need all features to be mask values
    isMask = K.all(isMask, axis=-1) #the entire output vector must be true
        #this second line is only necessary if the output features are more than 1

    #transform to float (0 or 1) and invert
    isMask = K.cast(isMask, dtype=K.floatx())
    isMask = 1 - isMask #now mask values are zero, and others are 1

    #multiply this by the inputs:
       #maybe you might need K.expand_dims(isMask) to add the extra dimension removed by K.all
     yTrue = yTrue * isMask   
     yPred = yPred * isMask

     return someLossFunction(yTrue,yPred)
```

---

If you have padding only for the input data, or if Y has no length, you can have your own mask outside the function:

```
masks = [
   [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
   [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
   [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
]
 #shape (samples, length). If it fails, make it (samples, length, 1). 

import keras.backend as K

masks = K.constant(masks)
```

Since masks depend on your input data, you can use your mask value to know where to put zeros, such as:

```
masks = np.array((X_train == maskValue).all(), dtype='float64')    
masks = 1 - masks

#here too, if you have a problem with dimensions in the multiplications below
#expand masks dimensions by adding a last dimension = 1.
```

And make your function taking masks from outside of it (you must recreate the loss function if you change the input data):

```
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    yTrue = masks*yTrue
    yPred = masks*yPred

    return someLossFunction(yTrue,yPred)
```

---

Does anyone know if keras automatically masks the loss function??
Since it provides a Masking layer and says nothing about the outputs, maybe it does it automatically?

Comment: Daniel - this is a really poor answer. Masks on length are dynamically assigned to `y_true` and `y_pred` so you cannot define it outside - as such masks are changing. If you do this in a manner which your provided - this will end up in a constant mask - which is not something what OP expects.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, thank you very much. My answer was indeed a bad answer.

Comment: Still not good compared to Yu-Yang's, but in case they don't use a masking layer, it may apply.

Comment: If you define the custom loss inside your model function you could access the mask tensor still. So this answer is valid.

Comment: @DanielMöller In your customLoss snipet: If the mask sets some yTrue and yPred values to zero, doesn't that mean that yTrue=yPred and the loss artificially goes up?

Comment: @Helen, the loss artificially goes down, but the really expected effect is the loss to be "constant" for those values, which mean they will never influence training. But adding some weight to the other elements to compensate for the zeros might be a good idea to balance things.

Answer (score 2):

I took both anwers and imporvised a way for Multiple Timesteps, single Missing target Values, Loss for LSTM(or other RecurrentNN) with return_sequences=True.

Daniels Answer would not suffice for multiple targets, due to `isMask = K.all(isMask, axis=-1)`. Removing this aggregation made the function undifferentiable, probably. I do not know for shure, since I never run the pure function and cannot tell if its able to fit a model.

I fused Yu-Yangs's and Daniels answer together and it worked.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input, LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np


mask_Value = -2
def get_loss(mask_value):
    mask_value = K.variable(mask_value)
    def masked_loss(yTrue,yPred):
        
        #find which values in yTrue (target) are the mask value
        isMask = K.equal(yTrue, mask_Value) #true for all mask values
    
        #transform to float (0 or 1) and invert
        isMask = K.cast(isMask, dtype=K.floatx())
        isMask = 1 - isMask #now mask values are zero, and others are 1
        isMask
        
        #multiply this by the inputs:
        #maybe you might need K.expand_dims(isMask) to add the extra dimension removed by K.all
        yTrue = yTrue * isMask   
        yPred = yPred * isMask
        
        # perform a root mean square error, whereas the mean is in respect to the mask
        mean_loss = K.sum(K.square(yPred - yTrue))/K.sum(isMask)
        loss = K.sqrt(mean_loss)
    
        return loss
        #RootMeanSquaredError()(yTrue,yPred)
        
    return masked_loss

# define timeseries data
n_sample = 10
timesteps = 5
feat_inp = 2
feat_out = 2

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, timesteps, feat_inp))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,timesteps, feat_out))

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu',return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, feat_inp)))
model.add(Dense(feat_out))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=get_loss(mask_Value))
model.summary()

# %%
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that Yu-Yang's answer does not appear to work on Tensorflow Keras 2.7.0

Surprisingly, `model.evaluate` does not compute `masked_loss` or `unmasked_loss`. Instead, it assumes that the loss from all masked input steps is zero (but still includes those steps in the mean() calculation). This means that every masked timestep actually reduces the calculated error!

```
#%% Yu-yang's example
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060797/3580080
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np
# Fix the random seed for repeatable results
np.random.seed(5)
tf.random.set_seed(5)

max_sentence_length = 5
character_number = 2

input_tensor = keras.Input(shape=(max_sentence_length, character_number))
masked_input = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0)(input_tensor)
output = keras.layers.LSTM(3, return_sequences=True)(masked_input)
model = keras.Model(input_tensor, output)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

X = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]],
              [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1]]])
y_true = np.ones((2, max_sentence_length, 3))
y_pred = model.predict(X)
print(y_pred)

# See if the loss computed by model.evaluate() is equal to the masked loss
unmasked_loss = np.abs(1 - y_pred).mean()
masked_loss = np.abs(1 - y_pred[y_pred != 0]).mean()

print(f"model.evaluate= {model.evaluate(X, y_true)}")
print(f"masked loss= {masked_loss}")
print(f"unmasked loss= {unmasked_loss}")
```

Prints:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.05340272 -0.06415359 -0.11803789]
  [ 0.08775083  0.00600774 -0.10454659]
  [ 0.11212641  0.07632366 -0.04133942]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
  [ 0.05394626  0.08956442  0.03843312]
  [ 0.09092357 -0.02743799 -0.10386454]
  [ 0.10791279  0.04083341 -0.08820333]
  [ 0.12459432  0.09971555 -0.02882453]]]
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 658ms/step - loss: 0.6865
model.evaluate= 0.6864957213401794
masked loss= 0.9807082414627075
unmasked loss= 0.986495852470398
```

(This is intended as a comment rather than an answer).