# Are masks in Tensorflow automatically consumed by loss and metric?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mask, transformer-model, loss

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060797/1516331) says:

> If there's a mask in your model, it'll be propagated layer-by-layer
> and eventually applied to the loss. So if you're padding and masking
> the sequences in a correct way, the loss on the padding placeholders
> would be ignored.

However in [TensorFlow's tutorial on Transformers](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#set_up_the_loss_and_metrics), the author has implemented custom [loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss) and [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric) where masks are computed and applied internally. Is this necessary?

Note in the [code of the Transformer model](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer#the_transformer), the author has deleted the keras mask:

```
    ....
    ....

    try:
      # Drop the keras mask, so it doesn't scale the losses/metrics.
      # b/250038731
      del logits._keras_mask
    except AttributeError:
      pass

    # Return the final output and the attention weights.
    return logits
```

Do we need to implement a custom loss and metric with mask, or we can use the built-in ones?